# what this command mean ? public static String status_path = "WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses";

Tags: android

Hello I bought project VPN from site and I found suddenly this code

`public static String status_path = "WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses";`
and this code
   `public static String video_upload_url = My_api + "api_video_upload.php";`

and this one
   `public static String video_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + mainFolderName + "Video/";`

as I know my VPN application didnt serve any whatsapp serves and there is nothing related to it

is that type of hacking or smth else or what I hope to find answer because I dont know the buyer

if its normal please explain to me

help me and thank you